# Start script missing error when running npm start in node-js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm-start

I am a beginner to react-js, I am trying to running my first app in reactjs but here getting error with npm start, please help me how to start npm.

node js version

```
v12.1.0
```

npm version

```
npm -v  6.9.0
```

Here my error while I am running npm,

```
C:\Users\NanduCn\first-project>npm start

> first-project@0.1.0 start C:\Users\NanduCn\first-project
> node server.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\NanduCn\first-project\server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:824:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! first-project@0.1.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the first-project@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NanduCn\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-30T10_38_04_898Z-debug.log
```

here my app package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "first-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I was changing to react-scripts start, its get another error:

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:431:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:17)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:431:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! first-project@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the first-project@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\NanduCn\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-30T11_26_54_037Z-debug.log
```

Comment: can you share your package.json

Comment: Could you share your Server.js code

Comment: @jack , head over to your project directory and type node server.js  and then enter.

Comment: hi vijay which means , which one,i have  a my app folder like

Comment: node_modules,  public,src,package.json,package-lock.json

Comment: which one is your server file ? means in which file you create http server and make it listen to a port ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is your react application then change your start in package.json by

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

not

```
"start": "node server.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

use

"start": "react-scripts start" but make sure you've server.js on the root directory. react-scripts start will look for server.js on root directory.